# R: promise already under evaluation

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, callstack

I understand that you are probably sick and tired of answering the same question again, but I am still getting the error discussed in [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357101/promise-already-under-evaluation-recursive-default-argument-reference-or-earlie) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073746/r-error-promise-already-under-evaluation-when-using-subset-in-function-but-no-er) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425348/unexpected-behaviour-with-argument-defaults):

> promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

even though I did follow the "cumbersome" advice of prepending `"."`:

```
show.large.objects.threshold <- 100000
show.large.objects.exclude <- c("closure")
show.large.objects <- function (.envir = sys.frame(),
                                threshold = show.large.objects.threshold,
                                exclude = show.large.objects.exclude) {
  for (n in print(ls(.envir, all.names = TRUE))) tryCatch({
    o <- get(n,envir = .envir)
    s <- object.size(o)
    if (s > threshold && !(typeof(o) %in% exclude)) {
      cat(n,": ")
      print(s,units="auto")
    }
  }, error = function(e) { cat("n=",n,"\n"); print(e) })
}
show.large.objects.stack <- function (.threshold = show.large.objects.threshold,
                                      skip.levels = 1,# do not examine the last level - this function
                                      .exclude = show.large.objects.exclude) {
  for (level in 1:(sys.nframe()-skip.levels)) {
    cat("*** show.large.objects.stack(",level,") ")
    print(sys.call(level))
    show.large.objects(.envir = sys.frame(level), threshold = .threshold, exclude = .exclude)
  }
}
```

but I still get errors:

```
> f <- function () { c <- 1:1e7; d <- 1:1e6; print(system.time(show.large.objects.stack())) }
> f()
*** show.large.objects.stack( 1 ) f()
[1] "c" "d"
c : 38.1 Mb
d : 3.8 Mb
*** show.large.objects.stack( 2 ) print(system.time(show.large.objects.stack()))
[1] "..." "x"  
n= ... 
<simpleError in get(n, envir = .envir): argument "..." is missing, with no default>
n= x 
<simpleError in get(n, envir = .envir): promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?>
*** show.large.objects.stack( 3 ) system.time(show.large.objects.stack())
[1] "expr"    "gcFirst" "ppt"     "time"   
n= expr 
<simpleError in get(n, envir = .envir): promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?>
          user         system        elapsed 
    0 (0.00ms)     0 (0.00ms) 0.002 (2.00ms)
```

1. So, what am I still doing wrong?
2. Do I *really* need the `.` in `.envir`? What about `.exclude` and `.threshold`?
3. Why do I get the `argument "..." is missing, with no default` error?
4. Why do I get the `promise already under evaluation` error?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend simplifying your example to something a little more minimal - you have a lot of interrelated function calls and it's not obvious what's going wrong. Adding to `.` argument names is definitely not necessary, and the error message is informative.  But it may be that because of lazy evaluation the error actually occurs earlier than when you see it.

Comment: I am having a *very* hard time reproducing the error.

Comment: @hadley: I added a reproducible test case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `f` is called a stack of 5 levels is built down to `show.large.objects`, which starts to evaluate the contents of the frames starting from the top.

```
f
  -> print
     -> system.time
        -> show.large.objects.stack
           -> show.large.objects
```

#### Level 1

```
f()
```

Everything ok here.

#### Level 2

```
print(system.time(show.large.objects.stack()))
```

When you call `ls(.envir, all.names)` on its frame you get

```
[1] "..." "x"
```

of which `...` is missing and throws error 3 when you call `get` on it, and `x = system.time(show.large.objects.stack())` is currently being evaluated and throws error 4.

#### Level 3

```
system.time(show.large.objects.stack())
```

whose `ls` gives you

```
[1] "expr"    "gcFirst" "ppt"     "time"
```

of which `expr = show.large.objects.stack()` is still currently being evaluated and throws another of error 4.

#### Level 4

```
show.large.objects.stack()
```

whose `ls` contain no sketchy things and completes without errors.

#### Bottom line

`show.large.frames()` must be evalutad on its own, not as an argument to any function, or it will throw errors. Why not letting it do the printing itself?

I found this very helpful

```
> debug(show.large.objects)
> f()
Browse[2]> lapply(sys.frames(), ls)
[[1]]
[1] "c" "d"

[[2]]
[1] "x"

[[3]]
[1] "expr"    "gcFirst" "ppt"     "time"   

[[4]]
[1] "level"       "skip.levels"

[[5]]
[1] "exclude"   "threshold"
```

Comment: so, what you are saying is that I should ignore the errors, right? what about "." in args?

Comment: It feels a bit dirty, but would get the job done I guess. With `try(..., silent=TRUE)` nobody would notice though. Is the purpose to display the size of all objects on all levels of the stack to see if anything grows out of hands?

Comment: I'm not aware of that the initial dot in argument names has any special function, but think people usually use it to mark special arguments related to how the function is executed rather than what it produces (like the `.inorder` and `.verbose` of `foreach`). Another reason I guess would be to separate arguments with otherwise identical names between different levels of the call stack for your own convenience, but it wouldn't solve any logical loop holes in your code.